# unable to display jquery of sparkline

Tags: jquery, class, html, visibility, sparklines

I want to display a jquery from a sparkline which is actually a  bar graph.I am not able to view it.Also I am new to jquery,

```
$("#sparkline").sparkline([5,6,7,2,0,4,2,4], {
    type: 'bar',
    height: '300',
    barWidth: 20,
    barSpacing: 10,
    barColor: '#615c5a',
    nullColor: '#3366cc '});
```

This is the code of the page it also is compatible with jquery 1.10

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $("#sparkline").sparkline([5,6,7,2,0,4,2,4], {
                type: 'bar',
                height: '300',
                barWidth: 20,
                barSpacing: 10,
                barColor: '#615c5a',
                nullColor: '#3366cc '});
            </script>
            </head>

            <body>
            <div id ="sparkline" />
            </body>
            </html>
```

To addon I have generated the code of sparkline from

```
http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-news
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#sparkline` element is not loaded yet. Try this:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#sparkline").sparkline([5,6,7,2,0,4,2,4], {
            type: 'bar',
            height: '300',
            barWidth: 20,
            barSpacing: 10,
            barColor: '#615c5a',
            nullColor: '#3366cc '});
        });
```

Read this: http://api.jquery.com/ready/
Note that not all browsers likes this syntax: `<div id ="sparkline" />`. Use this instead: `<div id ="sparkline" ></div>`.

**Update** 
I see you also forgot to include `sparkline` js file. You need to download it from [here](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-download) and after that to upload it to your server and to include it like you have included jQuery js file:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
```

Comment: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_lib_microsoft) I tried,but still I cant see code

Comment: thank you sir! this really helped. will definately vote once in 15 :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like sparkline.js is not compatible with jquery-1.9.1.min.js and above. Try out jquery-1.8.3.min.js it works perfect

Comment: this was my problem too! which wasn't documented on their site

Comment: I can confirm that I use Sparkline with jQuery v3.0.0 and it's works fine!